# Laravel Patch with request

Tags: php, laravel

I'm really enjoying Laravel and I have a question.

I am trying to create an edit form that uses a form partial. I am trying to follow the RESTful conventions as much as possible.

This is the case, I am trying to update an record in the database re using the request in the parameters like following:

```
public function tarief_range_update($id, TariefRangeRequest $request){
    $tarief = Tarief_range::find($id);
    $tarief->update($request->all);
    return redirect('/koerier/'. Input::get('koerier_id'));
}
```

I made the following route:

```
Route::patch('/tarief_range/{tarief_range}', ['as' => 'tarief_range.update', 'uses' => 'TarievenController@tarief_range_update']);
```

And I am using the following form open tag (with form-model binding)

```
{!! Form::model($tarief_range, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['TarievenController@tarief_range_update', $tarief_range->id]]) !!}
```

It generates the following error:

I know theres Route::resource but I rather configure it the "manual" way.

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::update() must
>   be of the type array, null given, called in
>   /home/vagrant/Code/my-first-app/app/Http/Controllers/TarievenController.php
>   on line 34 and defined

I have a resource route and it generates the same route (when I list them with route:list in artisan) and it has the same Form model binding and the same parameters in the update function.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Ok. Im stupid...

```
$tarief->update($request->all);
```

Should be

```
$tarief->update($request->all());
```